# ObjectBox query ToOne and ToMany With Or contains search term

Tags: java, objectbox

How to query ToOne and ToMany with search term by or and contains

```
@Entity
public class Purchase {

@Id
public long id;
public float total;
public Date createdOn;

public  ToOne<Supplier> supplier;
public ToMany<Item> items;
```

Would like to know how to query purchase.supplier.name or supplier.company or purchase.items.name or items.barcode where contains 'search term'
Tried the following but not working.

```
query.link(Purchase_.items).contains(Item_.name,mappedParam.get("search"))
                      .or().contains(Item_.barcode, mappedParam.get("search"));
query.link(Purchase_.supplier).contains(Supplier_.name, mappedParam.get("search"))
                        .or().contains(Supplier_.company, mappedParam.get("search"))
                        .or().contains(Supplier_.city, mappedParam.get("search"))
                        .or().contains(Supplier_.country, mappedParam.get("search"));

List<Purchase> objects = query.build().find(offsetLong,limitLong);
```

and also tried this

```
 query.link(Purchase_.items).contains(Item_.name,mappedParam.get("search"))
                        .or().contains(Item_.barcode, mappedParam.get("search"))
.or().link(Purchase_.supplier).contains(Supplier_.name, mappedParam.get("search"))
                        .or().contains(Supplier_.company, mappedParam.get("search"))
                        .or().contains(Supplier_.city, mappedParam.get("search"))
                        .or().contains(Supplier_.country, mappedParam.get("search"));
```

Above returns empty result, Any ideas?

Comment: The conditions from a link query are combined with the root query using AND. Maybe in your case that does not return results? To debug your queries try passing `.debugFlags(DebugFlags.LOG_QUERIES)` when building `BoxStore`.

Comment: Sorry, should have been `.debugFlags(DebugFlags.LOG_QUERY_PARAMETERS)`. Also see the new section at https://docs.objectbox.io/queries#debug-queries

Comment: Using AND does not work as well. it should return one result based on the search term.Relation between entity in ObjectBox is not as well supported as sql based db. ObjectBox works great in other point of views but not relations. For eample sort result based on ToOne is not supported. ToOne supplier, order the result based on supplier.name is not possible

Comment: Yes, ObjectBox's relations are pretty weak.  If order on a linked query, you get "java.lang.IllegalStateException: This call is not supported on sub query builders (links)".